# как сделать в телеграмм боте , чтобы записывало сообщение пользователя

Tags: telegram, бот

как сделать , чтобы сообщение пользователя, записывало в отдельний текстовий файл или отправляло в частную телеграмм группу? в данном случае, отправляет все сообщение разом , а тестовом файле выдает  The file was loaded in a wrong encoding: UTF-8 , как можно это исправить?
блок кода:
elif message.text == "Поделиться новостью":

```
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, поделитесь новостью и ссылкой на нее, "
                                      "после проверки мы ее опубликуем")
        with open("message.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write( f"{datetime.datetime.now()} - Пользователь {message.from_user.id} отправил сообщение: {message.text}\n")


    if len(news) != 0:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, мы рассмотрим вашу заявку в ближайшее время.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите кодировку `encoding='utf-8'`

В этой строчке:

```
with open("message.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as file:
```